# why margin-right is not showing when div is wider than window

Tags: css, window, size, width, margin

i want to know why the margin on the right side is not showing when a div is wider than window.

```
#red
{
    width:4000px;
    height:3000px;
    background:red;
    margin:20px;

}
```

I can see in the browser window, top,bottom and left are margin-ed correctly but no margin at the right,but it is working fine when div is narrower than window's width.Why it is so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the markup as well? This really depends on what element you're applying this #red to.

Comment: @Seed thanks for your reply, I did not used it in any project, just noticed that thing and wonder why? 
    <style>
*
{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
#red
{
  width:4000px;
  height:3000px;
  background:red;
  margin:20px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="red">
</div>
</body>

Comment: Well I only say it really depends on the element. Take a look at the box model and how it behaves: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
Most commonly used are inline, inline-block, block, and hidden. Also you may want to look at box-sizing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing